# Database connection failed: unable to create ado connection: [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen](Connect)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, ado

we are getting an error while logging in to our legacy system. Couldnt think about what the problem is. The people who developed the system seems unreachable. Its not happing every time and its intermittently.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your SQL Server instance is not set up with TCP/IP?

Go into surface area configuration and set the remote connections to both TCP/IP and Named Pipes and restart.